# LateInitializationError: Field 'media' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, api, class, dart, dio

got LateInitializationError: Field 'media' has not been initialized Error for Following Code... trying to get media from the Instagram API

**homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/models/data.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/utils/custom_dio_mixin.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = "HomePage";

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with CustomDioMixin {
  bool loading = true;
  bool error = false;
  late Media media;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: loading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : error
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => MediaWidget(
                      media: media,
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    try {
      final storage = GetStorage();
      final token = storage.read("accessToken");
      final response = await dio.get(
        'https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,timestamp&access_token=$token',
      );
      print("get data response => ${response.statusCode} ${response.data}");
    } catch (e) {
      print("get data failed");
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        error = true;
      });
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}

class MediaWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Media media;
  const MediaWidget({Key? key, required this.media}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: 6,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(media.mediaUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**here's data.dart**

```
class Media {
  Media({
    required this.id,
    required this.caption,
    required this.mediaUrl,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  int id;
  String caption;
  String mediaUrl;
  String timestamp;

  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Media(
        id: json["id"],
        caption: json["caption"],
        mediaUrl: json["media_url"],
        timestamp: json["timestamp"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "caption": caption,
        "media_url": mediaUrl,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      };
}
```

**and here's webview.dart** where I ask for the user authorization

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/screens/homepage.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/utils/custom_dio_mixin.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/constants.dart';

class IgWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const IgWebView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = "IgWebView";

  @override
  _IgWebViewState createState() => _IgWebViewState();
}

class _IgWebViewState extends State<IgWebView> with CustomDioMixin {
  late WebViewController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
      ),
      body: WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" +
            Constants.igClientId +
            "&redirect_uri=" +
            Constants.igRedirectURL +
            "&scope=user_profile,user_media &response_type=code",
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          this.controller = controller;
        },
        onPageStarted: (url) async {
          print("url is " + url);

          if (url
              .startsWith("https://aymen-ziouche.github.io/Gaming-website/")) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.id);
            // Navigator.pop(context);
            var uri = Uri.parse(url);
            final String? code = uri.queryParameters["code"];
            print("this's the code: $code");
            final response = await dio
                .post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data: {
              'client_id': Constants.igClientId,
              'client_secret': Constants.igClientSecret,
              'grant_type': "authorization_code",
              'redirect_uri': Constants.igRedirectURL,
              'code': code
            });
            final storage = GetStorage();

            await Future.wait([
              storage.write(
                  "accessToken", response.data["access_token"].toString()),
              storage.write("uid", response.data["user_id"].toString())
            ]);
            // print("response => ${response.statusCode} ${response.data}");
            print("the access Token is : " + storage.read("accessToken"));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

keep in mind that I need to use two different API's one to get the access token and one to get the actual media

Comment: You didn't assign `media` to anything in `HomePage`

Comment: More info, please? how cam i do that

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning `media` inside `getData` method. Check your `try` bloc snippet.

`Future<void> getData() async` is a future, it will take some time and will get null value on 1st frame, it is better to use nullable data if you like to skip using `FutureBuilder`.

Replace `late Media media` with `Media? media;`. And check null value where ever you are using.